# Get another value Object showing in Chosen JQUERY

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-chosen

How can I get the selected ID value from the chosen single DropDown?

ex:

`$("#select-id").chosen().val()`

Im getting the value of a country (name) but I need the ID to link with another DropDown.
This ID is the index of array of States, so when I choose a Country in the another DropDown Appear the array with all the State items.

Comment: check this out http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout JsFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/snS2P/). I create a simple example for you. Is that what you need?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                $(element).chosen();            
            },
            update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                $(element).trigger("liszt:updated");         
            }
};

var viewModel = {
    sample : ko.observableArray([{"name": "Sample Option 1" , "value" : 1 } , {"name": "Sample Option 2" , "value" : 2 }, {"name": "Sample Option 3" , "value" : 3 }]),
    selectedItemOne : ko.observable(),
    selectedItemTwo : ko.observable(),
    showOne : function(){ alert(this.selectedItemOne()) },
    showTwo: function(){ alert(this.selectedItemTwo()) }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: It's kind like that but, the 2nd select must be linked with the first.

Comment: also i'm trying to block the second if you don't pick nothing in the first, but don't worry about that.